# Android Studio:After logging with Facebook the app comes back to logging page and so the app is not loading the next activity

Tags: eclipse, web-services, parsing, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

noob here

**project details**

it's a blog kind'a app 
it was build in eclipse and my work is to upgrade it to android studio.

**i have done the followings**

1. build it, and running it on device but it's not loading to the next 
   activity
2. from log i can understand that it has something to do with 
       response call or data fetching from the server
3. i all so add gcm class because android studio did't load it during upgrading ,so there    could be a problem with that
4. i am uploading the log file

```html
<p>
  ba_cipher_suite:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
08-19 17:46:50.371 16504-16839/com.karma I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
08-19 17:46:50.371 16504-16839/com.karma I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
08-19 17:46:50.371 16504-16839/com.karma D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7f7f4bd900 sslWrite buf=0x7f7f44e000 len=598 write_timeout_millis=0
08-19 17:46:50.371 16504-16839/com.karma D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7f7f4bd900 sslRead buf=0x7f7f44e000 len=2048,timeo=0
08-19 17:46:51.229 16504-16504/com.karma E/jsonObject: {"id":"1147690341954122","first_name":"haha","gender":"male","last_name":"haha","link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/app_scoped_user_id\/1147220341954184\/","locale":"en_US","timezone":5.5,"updated_time":"2016-08-13T06:07:52+0000","verified":true,"email":"haha","friends":{"data":[{"name":"hshs","id":"1178432535548224"}],"paging":{"cursors":{"before":"QVFIUkJxME41NHIwbWhDTUtGdGFyLUpmeTUwbVpYR3VON25TcUtkTFFDT25ETDRTOWxQSWk1WlZAtYnVIcVNnN2NzeENobmZAzdU9SRWEzNGQ1cVJuNERUVl9n","after":"QVFIUkJxME41NHIwbWhDTUtGdGFyLUpmeTUwbVpYR3VON25TcUtkTFFDT25ETDRTOWxQSWk1WlZAtYnVIcVNnN2NzeENobmZAzdU9SRWEzNGQ1cVJuNERUVl9n"}},"summary":{"total_count":629}}}
08-19 17:46:51.233 16504-17533/com.karma I/System.out: open:https://graph.facebook.com/v3.4//11476569341954122/picture?access_token=EAAR5dXb01gYBAMFpe0HlIZAUM2L6ZB5Aq7SEaltq0cFK5lP2DufMq9S3q2bRqpCPATM7Kkbzdj8ecrwmZBndYB1UJ4qfy50atxHjb6C28zKUfHNZA98QvG482SuyQhPy7H3uCKzerrz09jghAA1ZAMqfKX6lmpfZBtkXmyb75H2oekJYpLkPN9n6GLU6CseP0ZD&format=json&redirect=false&sdk=android&type=larhe
08-19 17:46:51.234 16504-17533/com.karma I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:0
08-19 17:46:51.234 16504-17533/com.karma I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:0
08-19 17:46:51.234 16504-17533/com.karma I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
08-19 17:46:51.234 16504-17533/com.karma I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
08-19 17:46:51.235 16504-17533/com.karma D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7f7f4bb980 sslWrite buf=0x7f7f44d800 len=510 write_timeout_millis=0
08-19 17:46:51.235 16504-17533/com.karma D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7f7f4bb980 sslRead buf=0x7f7f44d800 len=2048,timeo=0
08-19 17:46:51.712 16504-16504/com.karma E/propicUrl: https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xaf1/v/61.0-1/p200x200/13906638_1159822301336988_1751633195181634948_n.jpg?oh=445e47fb03dd2aec5d7161f88c0cf955&oe=58470AB0&__gda__=1482379131_cc8673b209f9cb3b394eec9f210468a9
08-19 17:46:51.753 16504-16841/com.karma I/url :: url  call         : http://prod.karma.vote/login
08-19 17:46:51.758 16504-16841/com.karma I/System.out: isEmailSend:POST
08-19 17:46:51.759 16504-16841/com.karma I/System.out: getAllHeaders:POST
08-19 17:46:51.760 16504-16841/com.karma I/System.out: httpHeader:Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
08-19 17:46:51.760 16504-16841/com.karma I/System.out: this.mCheckHandler:android.net.Proxy$DefaultHttpRequestCheckHandler@1e1f71ae
08-19 17:46:51.763 16504-16841/com.karma I/System.out: [CDS][DNS] getAllByNameImpl netId = 0
08-19 17:46:51.763 16504-16841/com.karma D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=prod.karma.vote; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
08-19 17:46:51.764 16504-16841/com.karma D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
08-19 17:46:51.765 16504-16841/com.karma D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=prod.karma.vote; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
08-19 17:46:51.765 16504-16841/com.karma D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0
08-19 17:46:52.305 16504-16841/com.karma D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: prod.karma.vote get result from proxy >>
08-19 17:46:52.306 16504-16841/com.karma I/System.out: propertyValue:true
08-19 17:46:52.306 16504-16841/com.karma I/System.out: openConnection:2
08-19 17:46:52.307 16504-16841/com.karma I/System.out: [CDS][DNS] getAllByNameImpl netId = 0
08-19 17:46:52.307 16504-16841/com.karma D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=54.235.148.8; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
08-19 17:46:52.308 16504-16841/com.karma D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
08-19 17:46:52.312 16504-16841/com.karma I/System.out: [socket][2] connection /54.235.148.8:80;LocalPort=38590(15000)
08-19 17:46:52.313 16504-16841/com.karma I/System.out: [CDS]connect[/54.235.148.8:80] tm:15
08-19 17:46:52.317 16504-16841/com.karma D/Posix: [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.karma :80 
08-19 17:46:52.648 16504-16841/com.karma I/System.out: [socket][/192.168.1.52:38590] connected
08-19 17:46:52.649 16504-16841/com.karma I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:20000
08-19 17:46:52.650 16504-16841/com.karma I/System.out: [CDS]SO_SND_TIMEOUT:0
08-19 17:46:52.653 16504-16841/com.karma I/System.out: >doSendRequest
08-19 17:46:52.655 16504-16841/com.karma I/System.out: <doSendRequest
08-19 17:46:53.018 16504-16841/com.karma E/response :: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.35 - Error report</title><style type="text/css">H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px; background-color: #525D76; border: none;}</style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported</h1><div class="line"></div><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Request method 'POST' not supported</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.</u></p><hr class="line"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.35</h3></body></html>
08-19 17:46:53.022 16504-16504/com.karma E/Result: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.35 - Error report</title><style type="text/css">H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px; background-color: #525D76; border: none;}</style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported</h1><div class="line"></div><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Request method 'POST' not supported</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.</u></p><hr class="line"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.35</h3></body></html>
08-19 17:46:53.023 16504-16504/com.karma W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
08-19 17:46:53.027 16504-16504/com.karma W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
08-19 17:46:53.030 16504-16504/com.karma W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
08-19 17:46:53.030 16504-16504/com.karma W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
08-19 17:46:53.030 16504-16504/com.karma W/System.err:     at com.karma.SplashWithLoginActivity$LoginListener.onSuccess(SplashWithLoginActivity.java:469)
08-19 17:46:53.030 16504-16504/com.karma W/System.err:     at com.karma.Task.LoginTask.onPostExecute(LoginTask.java:52)
08-19 17:46:53.030 16504-16504/com.karma W/System.err:     at com.karma.Task.LoginTask.onPostExecute(LoginTask.java:15)
08-19 17:46:53.030 16504-16504/com.karma W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
08-19 17:46:53.030 16504-16504/com.karma W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
08-19 17:46:53.030 16504-16504/com.karma W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
08-19 17:46:53.030 16504-16504/com.karma W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
08-19 17:46:53.030 16504-16504/com.karma W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
08-19 17:46:53.030 16504-16504/com.karma W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5651)
08-19 17:46:53.030 16504-16504/com.karma W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-19 17:46:53.030 16504-16504/com.karma W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-19 17:46:53.030 16504-16504/com.karma W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
08-19 17:46:53.030 16504-16504/com.karma W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
08-19 17:46:59.382 16504-17531/com.karma D/MPlugin: createInstance(): Begin = 3757383
08-19 17:46:59.382 16504-17531/com.karma D/MPlugin: create Instance (two parameters) with : com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
08-19 17:46:59.383 16504-17531/com.karma D/MPlugin: Clazz exists on mapping table : false
08-19 17:46:59.383 16504-17531/com.karma E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
08-19 17:46:59.383 16504-17531/com.karma D/MPlugin: createInstance(): End = 3757383
08-19 17:46:59.402 16504-17531/com.karma I/System.out: open:https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/1259445320734214/activities?access_token=&format=json&sdk=android
08-19 17:46:59.440 16504-17531/com.karma I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:1
08-19 17:46:59.440 16504-17531/com.karma I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:1
  </p>
```

log 2 on dif device

```html
<p>
  I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-19 16:57:58.094 10607-10614/com.karma I/art: Debugger is no longer active
08-19 17:03:40.139 15383-15383/com.karma W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.karma-1/lib/arm64
08-19 17:03:40.216 15383-15383/com.karma V/GCMRegistrar: Registering receiver
08-19 17:03:40.218 15383-15383/com.karma D/GCMRegistrar: resetting backoff for com.karma
08-19 17:03:40.225 15383-15383/com.karma V/GCMRegistrar: Registering app com.karma of senders 13480167705
08-19 17:03:40.230 15383-15383/com.karma V/GCMRegistrar: Is registered on server: false
08-19 17:03:40.383 15383-16169/com.karma W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/tcmclient.jar
08-19 17:03:40.397 15383-15383/com.karma I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 52.0.2743.98 (code 275609850)
08-19 17:03:40.440 15383-15383/com.karma I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.ServiceWorkerControllerAdapter>
08-19 17:03:40.440 15383-15383/com.karma I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.ServiceWorkerControllerAdapter>
08-19 17:03:40.442 15383-15383/com.karma I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.TokenBindingManagerAdapter>
08-19 17:03:40.442 15383-15383/com.karma I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.TokenBindingManagerAdapter>
08-19 17:03:40.449 15383-15383/com.karma I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 2 ms (timestamps 3650-3652)
08-19 17:03:40.449 15383-15383/com.karma I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "52.0.2743.98", actual native library version number "52.0.2743.98"
08-19 17:03:40.693 15383-16188/com.karma D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
08-19 17:03:40.729 15383-15383/com.karma V/GCMBroadcastReceiver: onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
08-19 17:03:40.729 15383-15383/com.karma V/GCMBroadcastReceiver: GCM IntentService class: com.karma.GCMIntentService
08-19 17:03:40.733 15383-15383/com.karma V/GCMBaseIntentService: Acquiring wakelock
08-19 17:03:40.762 15383-16188/com.karma I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : d842ad3, Ia10634f51b
                                                   Build Date                       : 01/04/16
                                                   OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.05
                                                   Local Branch                     : mybranch17585849
                                                   Remote Branch                    : quic/LA.BR.1.2.6_rb1.7
                                                   Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                                   Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
08-19 17:03:40.768 15383-16188/com.karma I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-19 17:05:20.442 15383-15383/com.karma D/btn: ready to login
08-19 17:05:27.069 15383-15383/com.karma E/jsonObject: {"id":"1178432535548034","first_name":"haha","gender":"male","last_name":"haha","link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/app_scoped_user_id\/1178432535542234\/","locale":"en_US","timezone":5.5,"updated_time":"2016-07-16T18:21:29+0000","verified":true,"email":"haha,"friends":{"data":[{"name":"haha","id":"1147650341954122"}],"paging":{"cursors":{"before":"QVFIUlhUcGFSZAnM5V25PS2JfQnpZAaGUyU2NRUlNQUEFNd1BJaEJQRzJRTVE2TVZArQl9lSmtWc1A0VW5sTHpTTDNTU0g1YjIzOEVpM1VPM2RIM1AwUVFkdXR3","after":"QVFIUlhUcGFSZAnM5V25PS2JfQnpZAaGUyU2NRUlNQUEFNd1BJaEJQRzJRTVE2TVZArQl9lSmtWc1A0VW5sTHpTTDNTU0g1YjIzOEVpM1VPM2RIM1AwUVFkdXR3"}},"summary":{"total_count":173}}}
08-19 17:05:27.464 15383-15383/com.karma E/propicUrl: https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfl1/v/t1.0-1/p200x800/13690627_1164715453586409_7952552265506666391_n.jpg?oh=e7a41f737100c595c78faab6ffab8974&oe=584A4397&__gda__=1477796027_73364700dd9edfb125eb5ef49c5a0946
08-19 17:05:27.492 15383-18023/com.karma I/url :: url  call         : http://prod.karma.vote/login
08-19 17:05:27.495 15383-18023/com.karma W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/tcmclient.jar
08-19 17:05:28.414 15383-18023/com.karma E/response :: null
08-19 17:05:44.085 15383-15383/com.karma D/btn: ready to login
08-19 17:05:46.532 15383-15383/com.karma E/jsonObject: {"id":"1178432535548034","first_name":"haha","gender":"male","last_name":"haha","link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/app_scoped_user_id\/1178432535548022\/","locale":"en_US","timezone":5.5,"updated_time":"2016-07-16T18:21:29+0000","verified":true,"email":"haha","friends":{"data":[{"name":"haha","id":"1147650341954222"}],"paging":{"cursors":{"before":"QVFIUlhUcGFSZAnM5V25PS2JfQnpZAaGUyU2NRUlNQUEFNd1BJaEJQRzJRTVE2TVZArQl9lSmtWc1A0VW5sTHpTTDNTU0g1YjIzOEVpM1VPM2RIM1AwUVFkdXR3","after":"QVFIUlhUcGFSZAnM5V25PS2JfQnpZAaGUyU2NRUlNQUEFNd1BJaEJQRzJRTVE2TVZArQl9lSmtWc1A0VW5sTHpTTDNTU0g1YjIzOEVpM1VPM2RIM1AwUVFkdXR3"}},"summary":{"total_count":173}}}
08-19 17:05:46.918 15383-15383/com.karma E/propicUrl: https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofilu-ak-xfl1/v/t1.0-1/p270x200/13690627_1164715453586409_7952552265506666391_n.jpg?oh=e7a41f737100c595c78faab6ffab8974&oe=584A4397&__gda__=1477796027_73364700dd9edfb125eb5ef49c5a0946
08-19 17:05:46.920 15383-18051/com.karma I/url :: url  call         : http://prod.karma.vote/login
08-19 17:05:47.668 15383-18051/com.karma E/response :: null
08-19 17:06:15.806 18840-18840/com.karma W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.karma-1/lib/arm64
08-19 17:06:15.970 18840-18840/com.karma W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.karma-1/lib/arm64
08-19 17:06:16.050 18840-18840/com.karma V/GCMRegistrar: Registering receiver
08-19 17:06:16.051 18840-18840/com.karma D/GCMRegistrar: resetting backoff for com.karma
08-19 17:06:16.051 18840-18840/com.karma V/GCMRegistrar: Registering app com.karma of senders 13480167705
08-19 17:06:16.059 18840-18840/com.karma V/GCMRegistrar: Is registered on server: false
08-19 17:06:16.184 18840-18876/com.karma W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/tcmclient.jar
08-19 17:06:16.205 18840-18840/com.karma I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 52.0.2743.98 (code 275609850)
08-19 17:06:16.245 18840-18840/com.karma I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.ServiceWorkerControllerAdapter>
08-19 17:06:16.246 18840-18840/com.karma I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.ServiceWorkerControllerAdapter>
08-19 17:06:16.247 18840-18840/com.karma I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.TokenBindingManagerAdapter>
08-19 17:06:16.248 18840-18840/com.karma I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.TokenBindingManagerAdapter>
08-19 17:06:16.255 18840-18840/com.karma I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 2 ms (timestamps 9456-9458)
08-19 17:06:16.255 18840-18840/com.karma I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "52.0.2743.98", actual native library version number "52.0.2743.98"
08-19 17:06:16.295 18840-18888/com.karma D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
08-19 17:06:16.308 18840-18840/com.karma V/GCMBroadcastReceiver: onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
08-19 17:06:16.308 18840-18840/com.karma V/GCMBroadcastReceiver: GCM IntentService class: com.karma.GCMIntentService
08-19 17:06:16.310 18840-18840/com.karma V/GCMBaseIntentService: Acquiring wakelock
  </p>
```

Comment: Before migrating to android studio does the your app work? Try checking the document regarding [Migrate to Android Studio from Eclipse](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html). This will guide you on migrating your project to Android Studio. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

after some extensive work and search i found the problem it has something to do with api call which only returns data when you login from web then from app.

Thanks.